# Optional VB Parameters are required in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, optional-parameters

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088511/calling-a-vb-function-with-optional-parameters-with-a-c-sharp-call), but with a twist.

VB function declaration:

```
Public Shared Function MyFunc(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Num As Integer, Optional ByRef obj As Object = Nothing, Optional ByVal val As Integer = 0) As Boolean
```

When calling in C# (different solution, I copied over the `.dll`)

> *Error    164 No overload for method 'MyFunc' takes 2 arguments*

Metadata shows the function to be:

```
public static bool MyFunc(string Name, int Num, ref object obj, int val = 0);
```

Why did one `Optional` make it through while the other didn't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# doesn't support optional `ref` parameters. If you change `obj` to be a `ByValue` parameter, it should be fine.

If you try to *declare* an optional `ref` parameter in C#, you'll violate section 10.6.1 of the C# 4 spec:

> A *fixed-parameter* with a *default-argument* is known as an **optional parameter**.
>
> ...
>
> A `ref` or `out` parameter cannot have a *default-argument*.

The exception to this is for COM, where `ref` parameters are extremely common. When the C# compiler knows it's dealing with a COM component, it *will* allow you to omit optional `ref` parameters.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I swapped the order of the last two parameters, the C# project didn't have a problem accepting that, though the metadata was `public static bool MyFunc(string Name, int Num, int val = 0, ref object obj);` which is illegal. When trying to pass 2 parameters I got the `No overload...takes 2 arguments`. When trying to pass 3 parameters I got the `No overload...takes 3 arguments`. Interesting.

Comment: @JNF: The metadata you're showing is only a C# *representation* of whatever's in the IL. I suspect the real metadata for the original version was fine too - it's just that whatever you're using to translate that metadata into C# didn't work out what to do. I wouldn't just change the order of the parameters though - if that happens to work now, it's no guarantee that it will in the future. I'd change the signature to something which is also representable in C#.

Comment: no, well, that was just me playing Curious George. I ended up overloading in the VB.

Answer (score 5):

C# doesn't allow by-ref optional parameters. That's the reason.

See this other question+answer:

- [C# 4.0 optional out/ref arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870544/c-sharp-4-0-optional-out-ref-arguments)